# Integral of $\,\arcsin(x)/(x^2)$

Tags: integration

[image]

I did the integration by parts and got this expression, but then I am stuck on how to take it further. I tried substituting u=1-x^2, but then I had to do a partial fraction decomposition (which I did not take). Any hints or help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Try the substitution $u = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ in the last integral.

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr)

Answer (score 2):

Take $x = \sin u$ initially to get simple integral.

$$\int u \csc( u )\cot( u) du= -u\csc( u) + \int \csc (u) du\\
= -u \csc (u) +\ln|\cot( u )-\csc (u)| + c.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sqrt{1-x^2}=t$.

Thus, $-\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=dt$ and
$$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=-\int\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}\right)dt=$$
$$=-\int\frac{1}{x^2}dt=-\int\frac{1}{1-t^2}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int\left(\frac{1}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t+1}\right)dt=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{t-1}{t+1}\right|+C=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+1}\right|+C.$$

Answer (score -1):

I wrote my answer for this question, click 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDJwC.png)  to see the image.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.